# Where to place removeHash() using NPM react-scrollable-anchor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url

Pardon for this elementary issue.

I'm trying to figure out where to place `removeHash()` using the NPM `react-scrollable-anchor`. Link to the documentation is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scrollable-anchor#clear-the-url-hash-without-affecting-scroll-location-at-all).

Currently, the hash is removed only after I refresh the page. After the refresh, the location stays where the anchor is. What I would like to happen is that everytime I click an anchor link the URL removes the hash without the need to refresh.

I currently have `removeHash()` in my main `index.js` file as seen below.

I did try placing `removeHash()` at the bottom of my components right above the export statements but that didn't work.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { removeHash } from 'react-scrollable-anchor';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
removeHash();
```

Comment: have you tried placing it inside `App`

Comment: I did. Same results as how I have it now in the main `index.js`. It doesn't clear the hash after each click. It only clears after I refresh the page.